# Is there a way for a matlab function to access all variables in a script

Tags: matlab

I have a script with lots of variables (10-30), and in a for loop I do some processing using basically every variable. I have a helper script so that the interior of the loop looks clean.

main script

```
a=2;b=5;c=8;d=10;%and many many more
for i=1:1000
    helper;
end
```

I want to turn helper into a function, primarily because this would allow me to have the helper script (now a function) at the bottom of the main file. But I definitely do not want to individually pass every variable and every variable that I have yet to need in this project.

What I really need is a goto, but matlab doesnt have it.

Comment: You could turn the main script in a function, and let `helper` be a [nested function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html), that would share the variables. Otherwise, you could put some variables in a struct (e.g. `P.a = 2; P.b = 5`), and then pass this struct to the function.

Comment: Pretty a good solution. So the inner function will have access to the original function? This isn't how it works with practically any other programming language, right? Anyways, i wish this applied to scripts as well.

Comment: Yes. In Matlab, nested (inner) functions have read and write access to all the variables in the enclosing function. Not gonna work in scripts. Scripts suck; just use functions. ;)

Answer (score 2):

There are many solutions to this. In [rinkert's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69123880/is-there-a-way-for-a-matlab-function-to-access-all-variables-in-a-script#comment122171693_69123880) you've gotten the only one that is good coding practice: put the variables in a struct, then pass the struct into your function. I highly recommend that you do that. Using [nested functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html) is not a terrible solution either, though it could be a lot more difficult to manage (variable visibility rules are funny in nested functions, I find it confusing at times).

Here I'm going to give you the worst possible solution: [`evalin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalin.html). **You should not do this**, I post this here for educational purposes only.

`evalin` allows a function to retrieve a variable in the caller's workspace:

```matlab
a=2;b=5;c=8;d=10;%and many many more
for i=1:1000
    helper;
end

function helper
    % NEVER DO THIS IN PRACTICE
    a = evalin('caller','a');
    b = evalin('caller','b');
    c = evalin('caller','c');
    d = evalin('caller','d');
    % do computations....
    assignin('caller','result',result);
end
```

Note that a function `result = helper(a,b,c,d)` is much more efficient and much easier to maintain because it's clear what is going on. `evalin` makes for surprising results, and `assignin` even more so. **Do not use this**.

There are a few legitimate uses of these functions. For example, I've written a GUI that allows a MATLAB user easier access to a set of functions, but is meant to work in conjunction with the interactive MATLAB command prompt. The GUI would fetch variables from the 'base' workspace, evaluate function calls in the 'base' workspace, and write new variables to the 'base' workspace. Running a function within the GUI is just like running it at the command prompt. There is no other way of accomplishing this other than using `evalin` and `assignin`.

Comment: Good answer, with appropriate emphasis on the "do not do this" part. ;)

Comment: @AndrewJanke Do you think I made it clear enough that this is bad advice? :D

Comment: Well I would have used all caps in addition to the bold in the main text, but I respect your stylistic choices. :)

Answer (score 0):

although it's not good coding conduct, you could use [global](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html) variables :
for example :

```
global a;
a= 5;

function out =test()
    global a;
    out=2*a;
end
```